# How to link USR-7S4 with TI CC2640R2F through UART programming?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, uart, texas-instruments, lte, 4g

USR-7S4 is an LTE module and I just want to check whether it can communicate with CC2640R2F BLE module.

Comment: Have you had a look at the documentation? https://www.pusr.com/download/M2M/USR-LTE-7S4-User-Manual-V1.0.3.1.pdf Chapter 2.2 describes the serial port

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, a site about programming problems, software algorithm and software tools. Questions about electronic hardware are better suited on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/. Question regarding specific hardware features should probably be directed to the manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

We can use UART communication and transmit the AT initialization commands described for the module. Once done with one AT command we need to accept the response using BLE and immediately clear that AT command so that the next command can be given. This helps to receive the new responses from the 0th position of the buffer. This clearing can be done using:  "memset(rxBuf,0,sizeof(rxBuf));" commands.